# Serial port awaiter - cancel if device is not responding for 5 secs | when flag doesnt change

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, serial-port

I'm trying to make a app that comunicates with a device through serial port.
I'm lacking the idea to "stop" the program when there is no response for some time.

I got the idea to make a flag that I'm setting to false while sending data, in my DataReceiveEvent I'm changing the flag to true. But at the same time I want a timer that if no response is registered will fire an event.
I thought of using async Tasks.

```
            var delay = Task.Run(async () => { await Task.Delay(3000); return false;});
            var flag = Task.Run(async () => { await isFlagChanged(); return isFlagChanged});
            var result = await Task.WhenAny(delay, flag);
            bool res = await result;
```

but I don't know how to determine if flag had changed. I don't even know if that's a good idea...
Any sugestions?

Comment: Do you want your API to be async or sync? If you want to use async, you could use [CancellationToken with timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time).

Comment: Okay, using cancellation token how should my function to detect changes work? 
while(!flag) {do nothing}
//when flag chagnes
return true

Answer (score 0):

Have your Async Task reset a CancellationTokenSource timeout each time it receives information.

If it doesn't receive any data then the CancelationToken will fire and your Task can exit.  Your function that will be reading the serial port, needs to be checking the `CancellationToken`.

eg:,

```
    static async Task MyTaskAsync(CancellationTokenSource cts)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;
        var rnd = new Random();

        while (true)
        {
            var next = rnd.Next(10);
            Console.WriteLine(next);

            if (next == 1)
            {
                await Task.Delay(500, ct);  // Simulate receiving no data by waiting longer the timeout
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.Delay(100, ct);  // Simulate receiving data by waiting less than the timeout
                cts.CancelAfter(500);
            }

            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

    }

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(500); // Auto cancel after 500ms
        try
        {
            await MyTaskAsync(cts);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The task exited because the Cancellation timeout period expired.");
        }
    }
```